# What is the performance price of mapping a SortedSet in Hibernate?

Tags: performance, hibernate, sortedset

In one of my mapped classes, I have a `Set` field mapped to the DB via hibernate. I now need this collection to be sorted according to some logic, which I wrote into a new `Comparator` implementation. I changed the field type to `SortedSet`, added this `Comparator` as an attribute to my hibernate mapping (XML, no annotations), assuming Hibernate retrieved all objects from the DB, then sorts using the given `Comparator`.

A colleague brought up the possibility that there is a performance price hidden here, as Hibernate actually uses insertion sort, meaning it calls the `compare` method numerous times for every object it loads. Is this true? Are there any other performance issues to mapping a sorted collection?